# View Controllers that are popped from the navigation stack seem to still exist in the back

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xcode8

I have three different view controllers in my project, all with their own overridden viewWillAppear functions, with print statements to identify which view controller's function is being called when the application is running. These controllers are all under a navigation controller, and for simplicity, I'll refer to them as View Controllers A, B, and C.

However, the problem is that when I navigate from View Controller A to View Controllers B and C, then use the "back" button on the navigation bar to return to viewController A, it seems like viewControllers B and C aren't dismissed completely. I checked the navigation stack count using self.navigationController.viewControllers.count and it's properly returning count = 1 (meaning that the only view controller on the stack is A), yet if I minimize the app and bring it back to the foreground again, the viewWillAppear functions are still being called by the B and C view controllers, even though they should have been popped off the stack. Furthermore, if I go back and forth between A and B multiple times, stay at A, then minimize the app and open it up again, the viewWillAppear method will be also be called multiple times, the number of occurrences being equal to however many times I moved between the two controllers.

Note: I am using a NotificationCenter Observer to tell the controllers to call viewWillAppear/viewDidDisappear when the app comes into the foreground or goes into the background.

Here is how I'm using the observer:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NSLog("View Controller A: viewWillAppear called")
    /*
    Some code here
    */
}

func willEnterForeground(){
    viewWillAppear(false)
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```

Sorry for the wall of text, I didn't know how to better describe this issue. This seems like a somewhat generalized problem, so I didn't post any code. If anyone has any clue on what the problem may be here, or would like me to post some more code, please let me know.

Thanks!

Update: RESOLVED. For anyone who stumbles upon this problem and happens to see this post, I left my solution in the comments section below.

Comment: Did you store the created view controllers somewhere else (e.g. as a property)? Seems those view controllers are not deallocated after you popped them from the stack.

Comment: Calling `viewWillAppear(false)` is an odd (and not recommended) thing to do - but I don't know if that has anything to do with what you're seeing. Can you replicate the issue in a small example?

Comment: @alanlo @DonMag
I think alan pointed me in the right direction here. The problem seems to be that by adding the observers to the view controllers and not removing them when they were popped, it kept them from being deallocated.

My solution was to implement a custom back bar button item for the navigation controller and call `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` on the view controllers before they were popped. Thanks for the help guys.